# OpenAI: Stream interrupted (client disconnected)

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I'm trying OpenAI.

I have prepared the training data, and used `fine_tunes.create`. Several minutes later, it showed `Stream interrupted (client disconnected)`.

```
$ openai api fine_tunes.create -t data_prepared.jsonl
Upload progress: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████| 47.2k/47.2k [00:00<00:00, 44.3Mit/s]
Uploaded file from data_prepared.jsonl: file-r6dbTH7rVsp6jJMgbX0L0bZx
Created fine-tune: ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h
Streaming events until fine-tuning is complete...

(Ctrl-C will interrupt the stream, but not cancel the fine-tune)
[2022-12-02 11:10:08] Created fine-tune: ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h
[2022-12-02 11:10:23] Fine-tune costs $0.06
[2022-12-02 11:10:24] Fine-tune enqueued. Queue number: 11

Stream interrupted (client disconnected).
To resume the stream, run:

  openai api fine_tunes.follow -i ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h
```

I tried `fine_tunes.follow`, several minutes later, it still failed:

```
$ openai api fine_tunes.follow -i ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h
[2022-12-02 11:10:08] Created fine-tune: ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h
[2022-12-02 11:10:23] Fine-tune costs $0.06
[2022-12-02 11:10:24] Fine-tune enqueued. Queue number: 11

Stream interrupted (client disconnected).
To resume the stream, run:

  openai api fine_tunes.follow -i ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h
```

`openai api fine_tunes.list` showed:

```
$ openai api fine_tunes.list
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_at": 1669975808,
      "fine_tuned_model": null,
      "hyperparams": {
        "batch_size": 2,
        "learning_rate_multiplier": 0.1,
        "n_epochs": 4,
        "prompt_loss_weight": 0.01
      },
      "id": "ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h",
      "model": "curie",
      "object": "fine-tune",
      "organization_id": "org-YyoQqNIrjGHYDnKt9t3T6x2J",
      "result_files": [],
      "status": "pending",
      "training_files": [
        {
          "bytes": 47174,
          "created_at": 1669975808,
          "filename": "data_prepared.jsonl",
          "id": "file-r6dbTH7rVsp6jJMgbX0L0bZx",
          "object": "file",
          "purpose": "fine-tune",
          "status": "processed",
          "status_details": null
        }
      ],
      "updated_at": 1669975824,
      "validation_files": []
    }
  ],
  "object": "list"
}
```

And `$ openai api completions.create -m ft-JRGzkYfXm7wnScUxRSBA2M2h -p aprompt` returned `Error: That model does not exist (HTTP status code: 404)`.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Experiencing same issue. Could it be that queues are overcrowded, thus leading queue time to exceed some timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a temporary issue of OpenAI, the team fixed that.

Comment: The error is coming again!

Comment: still getting this error today!

Comment: Is not temporary so far, it's permanent

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, there is a problem with the OpenAI API. (see: [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenAI/comments/105ri0t/anyone_else_having_trouble_uploading_their_data/) and [this issue on Git](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/173)) I downgraded my version to v.0.25 by running
`pip install openai==0.25.0`
That fixed it for me. Although, to be fair, you can expect this to be fixed in the future.

Comment: Is this supposed to be fixed yet, I am continually getting this issue.

Comment: As of today, it does not seem to be fixed yet, although I didd't do any more finetunes to test it. Until it is fixed, I recommend sticking with version 0.25 - at least for fine tuning. After you finished your fine tuning, you can revert and use your fine-tuned model with the current version.

Comment: After about a minute, the fine tuning disconnects. Even on version 0.25. Seems like the issue is server side

Comment: I don't think you need to stay connected for your fine-tuning. Once you've uploaded the files, OpenAI will do the rest for you. If I remember correctly, there is a command to reconnect to the output stream of your fine-tuning as well. Once your fine-tuning is finished, you can use the CLI to view your fine-tuned models. Another way to see it is to log into the OpenAI Playground and choose your fine-tuned model on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that stream interruption is only preventing you from viewing progress not actually fine-tuning. Your job is already in the queue.

The bad news is that you never know how long will it take. According to https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

> Streams events until the job is done (this often takes minutes, but
> can take hours if there are many jobs in the queue or your dataset is
> large)

You may periodically check the status of your job using:

`openai api fine_tunes.list`

More info:

https://community.openai.com/t/stream-interrupted-client-disconnected-during-fine-tunes-follow/70334/20

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error and end up creating a python program to monitor the progress without running the commands manually. Simply change the ID and you are all set to go.

```
import subprocess
import time
import threading
import json
import requests

class FineTuneMonitor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmd1 = "openai api fine_tunes.follow -i ft-YOUR_ID_TO_MONITOR"
        self.cmd2 = "openai api fine_tunes.list"
        self.id = "**YOUR_ID_TO_MONITOR**"  # Set the ID of your fine-tune process
        self.process = None
        self.success = False

    def run_command(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

        while True:
            output = self.process.stdout.readline().decode()
            print(output.strip())

            if self.process.poll() is not None:
                break

            if 'Stream interrupted' in output:
                self.process.kill()
                return False

        return True

    def monitor_status(self):
        while True:
            output = subprocess.check_output(self.cmd2, shell=True).decode()
            data = json.loads(output)
            status = next((item["status"] for item in data["data"] if item["id"] == self.id), None)

            if status is None:
                print("Could not find status for the given ID.")
                return

            print(f"Status: {status}")

            if status != "pending":
                if self.process is not None:
                    self.process.kill()
                self.success = True
                return

            time.sleep(10)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.monitor_status).start()

        while not self.success:
            self.run_command()
            print("Stream was interrupted, retrying in 10 seconds...")
            time.sleep(10)

monitor = FineTuneMonitor()
monitor.start()
```

This script creates a FineTuneMonitor class that encapsulates the logic for running and monitoring OpenAI commands. The start method starts the status monitoring in a new thread and then repeatedly runs the first command until it completes successfully. The monitor_status method runs the second command every 10 seconds and kills the first command's process if the status changes from "pending".

Replace self.id with the ID of your fine-tune process. The script assumes that the status is located under data -> status in the output of the second command. If the structure of the output changes, you'll need to update the script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I kept ruining this command:
openai api fine_tunes.follow -i <YOUR_FINE_TUNE_JOB_ID>

until it got a Queue number