# Stream interrupted (client disconnected). To resume the stream, run: openai api fine_tunes.follow -i ft-***, while fine tuning openai

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3

(Ctrl-C will interrupt the stream, but not cancel the fine-tune)
[2023-02-22 07:37:41] Created fine-tune: ft-LaoFNTDDUfQbmxTHkViCcuc2

Stream interrupted (client disconnected).
To resume the stream, run:

openai api fine_tunes.follow -i ft-LaoFNTDDUfQbmxTHkViCcuc2

What's the issue I used two version of OpenAi 0.25.0 and 0.26.5
For both the version I am getting the same error

Can anyone help solve the above problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**It was a temporary issue of OpenAI**

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issues in monitoring the OpenAI fine-tuning process, then you can have a look at the Python script @ [OpenAI: Stream interrupted (client disconnected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74666268/openai-stream-interrupted-client-disconnected/76827554#76827554)